# Connect to another server from Ubuntu and retreive files

Tags: mysql, sql-server, laravel, ubuntu

I have a Laravel project in Ubuntu 16.04, and I need to import a database from another server.

So the steps that I'm doing now :

1. I Connect to my "customer" Windows Server.
2. Execute a `PowerShell` command that exports an SqlServer
   Database tables to CSV files.
3. I copy those CSV to my local machine.
4. I connect to my Ubuntu server and copy those CSV files to it from my machine.
5. I run a PHP script that imports those CSV files to a MySQL Database.

I need to do all that from my Ubuntu server to be able to do all this in one command, that I'll be executing everyday at 3 AM.

Can you show me the path to achieve this ? Thank you.

Comment: would it not be easier to connect to the `sql server` on the customer server, and just retrieve the records using sql ?

Comment: I have to be able to run one command on my server that can do everything, because it will be set as a crontab command later, and be executed autmatically everyday at 3 AM for example.

Comment: Why do you need to use Powershell too? BCP would likely be a better option. But all in one command? You're suggesting you want to run commands on 2 different computers (Powershell on the Windows host, and the PHP on the Ubuntu one). At least stick to running the commands on  one computer.

Comment: Did you try a linked server solution? Once the source server is linked, you may import data with a simple `INSERT my_local_table SELECT ... FROM src_server.src_db.dbo.my_remote_table`